# What is the difference between inherit from an abstract class and from a concrete class? Why would we need the latter?

Tags: class, inheritance, abstract-class

I Know Abstract is a class something else extends on 
but why would anything want to extend a non-abstract class?
Is it generally a better convention to only extend from abstract classes as then they cant be instantiated so it doesn't do weird stuff?

an example of both showing why one must be abstract/not abstract to show distinction would be awesome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should really be on Programmers.SE, but it would be rapidly closed as a [duplicate of this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176692/why-should-a-class-be-anything-other-than-abstract-or-final-sealed/176696#176696)

Comment: That's actually not a bad question considering that now, in Java 8, we have default methods.

Comment: @alfasin It's not a bad question, it's just "asked-and-answered"

Comment: I couldn't find an answer easy for a beginner to read :/

Comment: @durron597 the link you posted discusses abstract vs. final/sealed. That's not the same question. Further, I didn't write my first comment as a comment to yours.

Comment: @durron597 Don't forget that this is a beginner level question. The answer that you link to talks about `sealed classes` and `ORM` and other such stuff. A beginner needs visual examples. He can't comprehend things like seasoned programmers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many situations where you would want to extend from concrete classes.

Consider a class called `Device`. Each device has a name and can be in three states, `ON`, `OFF` or `INIT_STATE`. Each device can be turned `on` or `off`.

```
public class Device {
    private String name;
    private static final int ON = 1;
    private static final int OFF = 0;
    private static final int DEVICE_INIT_STATE = -1;
    private int deviceStatus = DEVICE_INIT_STATE;

    public Device(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public final void on() {
        if (deviceStatus==OFF || deviceStatus==DEVICE_INIT_STATE) {
            deviceStatus = ON;
            System.out.println(getName() + " turned on");
        } else {
            System.out.println(getName()+" is already on");
        }
    }

    public final void off() {
        if (deviceStatus==ON) {
            deviceStatus = OFF;
            System.out.println(getName() + " turned off");
        } else {
            System.out.println(getName()+" is not on");
        }
    }

    public void undo() {
        if (deviceStatus==ON) {
            off();
        } else if(deviceStatus==OFF){
            on();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    protected boolean isON() {
        return deviceStatus==ON;
    }
}
```

Consider a `Stereo` which is also a `Device` but has additional functionality such as `openTray`, `closeTray` and `setCd` and can be in 5 states that is `ON`, `OFF`, `TRAY_OPEN`, `TRAY_CLOSE` and `INIT_STATE`.

```
public class Stereo extends Device {

    private String cd;
    private static final int TRAY_OPEN = 1;
    private static final int TRAY_CLOSE = 0;
    private static final int TRAY_INIT_STATE = -1;
    protected int trayState = TRAY_INIT_STATE;

    public Stereo(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void openTray() {
        if(!isON()) {
            System.out.println(getName()+" is not on");
        } else if(trayState==TRAY_CLOSE || trayState == TRAY_INIT_STATE) {
            trayState = TRAY_OPEN;
            System.out.println("Tray opened for "+getName());
        }  else {
            System.out.println(getName()+" tray is already open");
        }

    }

    public void closeTray() {
        if(!isON()) {
            System.out.println(getName()+" is not on");
        } else if(trayState==TRAY_OPEN) {
            trayState = TRAY_CLOSE;
            System.out.println("Tray closed for "+getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println(getName()+" tray is not open");
        }

    }

    public void undo() {
        if(trayState==TRAY_OPEN) {
            closeTray();
        } else if(trayState==TRAY_CLOSE) {
            openTray();
        }
    }

    public void setCd(String cd) {
        this.cd = cd;
    }

    public String getCd() {
        return cd;
    }


}
```

Stereo inherits the `on` and `off` methods from `Device`. You can instantiate a basic device such as a light bulb as follows :

```
Device lightBulb = new Device("Living room light bulb");
```

On the other hand, you could instantiate a Stereo as follows :

```
Stereo stereo = new Stereo("Stereo in my heart");
```

The take-away from the above example is that a light bulb is a basic `Device` that can only be turned `on` or `off`. A `Stereo` on the other hand is a more specialized kind of `Device` which can be turned `on` and `off` but also has `openTray` and `closeTray` functionality. Since `Stereo` is a `Device`, it inherits the `on` and `off` method from `Device`. This is an example where the super class has a use-case where it can be instantiated and does not need to be abstract.

Comment: great example bot, I was wondering if you could give me an example of why I would not want to instantiate the parent(abstract) ? Just so I can see a clear distinction between options(its been driving me nuts trying to get my head around it) Cheers!

Comment: would the abstract way of doing it be creating LightBulb bulb = new LightBulb() and have it extend abstract class Device { } ? and is that not as good way of doing it  why would that be?

Comment: I would have taken a different example had you mentioned that you wanted an example of when a class must be abstract as well. It doesn't seem to be a part of your question. Post a new question and let this one be considered as done? ;) To answer your question about `Device` being `abstract`. Think of it this way, is there some operation that the `Device` class would rather have each of it's subclass take care of without providing a default implementation for it? If yes, create an `abstract` method in `Device` for this operation and make `Device` `abstract`.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two orthogonal things imho.

In the former you want to ensure that no one can instantiate your abstract class. Plus give some additional goodies such as declare some common methods.

In inheritance you are extending a class to add / update some functionality.If you are parent class can be instantiated - you dont need to make it abstract.